# Milo does not show the version number anymore when I create a standalone assembly

Tags: opc-ua, milo

Normally the Milo OPC UA client prints the version number:
Eclipse Milo OPC UA Stack version: **0.5.3**

But when I create a single jar (with Maven) then Milo shows:
Eclipse Milo OPC UA Stack version: **dev**

I mean it is not really a problem but I wonder why it is like this and sure it would be more nice if the correct version number would be shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version numbers are placed in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` files during the build and if your Uber-jar process removed or replaced the manifest with one from another dependency then there is no way for the version to be read any more and it will default to `dev`.